# Update all textfields of multiple products by one button

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento

we are using magento multi vendor site

For single Product we are displaying price, selling price , quantity...etc in vendor account.

we gave an option for vendor to update all the textfields of single product by clicking on one "update" button.

we are using following code for this.

**PHTML**

```
<button id="update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateAllFields('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;"  >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function updateAllFields(product_id) {
            updateFieldPrice(product_id);
            updateFieldSpecialPrice(product_id);
            updateField(product_id);

            }
```

[image]

Now we want to provide an option for update all textfields of multiple products by clicking on one "update" button. 
Ex: for one product we will edit price , for second we will edit price and qty, for third price, quantity , special price . we edit all textfield values and enter the button "save all".

In the image, last but one column, you can see "save all" button. once we click on that button it should save all the field values.

Comment: Good luck with that :)

Comment: @Epodax Thanks a lot.....

Comment: need a complete file code can you send me..

Comment: sure, i will send you.....

Comment: please check : http://pastebin.com/vXps0NFq

Comment: i need something like this : https://sellercentral.amazon.in/hz/inventory/

Comment: your already using the form massactiondelete i need that code too..

Comment: we are using only that file code. can you help me in finding in which file that " massactiondelete " code is present ?

Comment: can u send me code on email?

Comment: please check mail...

Comment: `marketplace/controllers/MarketplaceaccountController/`  nedd this file too

Comment: which filed you are want to update?

Comment: right now price and selling price, in future i will add more fields. please implemet code like it shoul work for all fields....

Comment: i see price and special price filed only..

Comment: sure, you can check that now....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add product id as in array same as for price and special price

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_mass_update[]"  value="<?php echo $products->getEntityId(); ?>"/>
<input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>
    <input class="ama1" type = "text" id = "specialprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name = "specialprice[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>" onblur="updateFieldSpecialPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>')" style = ""/>
```

for update all record

```
public function massupdatesellerproAction(){
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $ids= $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_mass_update');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $special= $this->getRequest()->getParam('specialprice');
        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
    $product->setPrice($price[$key]);
    $product->setSpecialPrice($special[$key]);
    $product->save();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully deleted from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in MarketplaceaccountController.php on line 1219

Comment: is i have to replace the old html code for price and special price or i need to add this code ?

Comment: where i have to add this l ine : <input type="hidden" name="product_mass_update[]"  value="<?php echo $products->getEntityId(); ?>"/>

Comment: once we refresh the page, its not saving in database : http://2.kidsdial.com/index.php/marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/

Comment: `onclick="changeaction()" `  update this on update button the form is not submit

Comment: i chnaged onclick="changeaction" to = > onclick="changeaction()" but its giving 404 error after clicking update button

Comment: its updating fine, but can you help me to update without reloading the page as like :

https://sellercentral.amazon.in/hz/inventory/

Comment: for that post a new question. i did that kind of work too .. i think same question you posted on magento too?

Comment: please check here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87785/wrong-quantity-is-displaying-in-backend-becasuse-of-over-riding/98123?noredirect=1#comment132048_98123

Comment: thanks ,please check when you are free, otherwise evening.